# How can I make a css modification on a onScroll() event permanent?

Tags: jquery, css, events, onscroll

I want an `div` (in this case it's a "scroll back to top") to appear when the user has reached a scroll point in my page, I am using the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > 1500) {
            $('#backtotop').css({'display':'block'});
        } else {
            $('#backtotop').css({'display':'none'});
        }
    });
 });
```

It works perfectly, save for the fact that the div only appears when one is actively scrolling, the css of `#backtotop` is set as "display:none" in the css stylesheet, if I do it the other way around and set it to `"display:block"` than I have the opposite problem, the div is always there but fades out when I scroll above the 1500 value... only to appear again the moment I stop scrolling.

So basically I want the div to appear (like it does) when I reach a scroll point, but I also want it to stay when I stop scrolling (which it doesn't)

Comment: i don't really know how to solve this, since i don't even understand the entire question. But i suggest you the following plugin `http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/` which exactly does what you want, and that in a very simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/6gAHT/2/

You want to show `To Top` div after scrolling some point, then click, it will go to top and hide.??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > 500) {
            $('#backtotop').show();
        } else {
            $('#backtotop').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#backtotop').on('click', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the question. The scrolling back to the top is already handled with a href="#top" and the scrolling is handled with another plugin. The problem is that the #backtotop div should not disappear after the user stops scrolling.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with my jquery version, the problem is updating makes other plugins get messed up. But it seems to work properly, thanks again.